# Surround multiple lines with quotes

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, live-templates

I'm trying to build a live template that will work like the 'wrap in comment' live template (that puts a `//` before each selected line). For example, select multiple lines of text, click `Code` > `Surround With` > `Single quotes` (custom live template) and quotes will appear around each line.

E.g. from:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

to:

```
'text1'
'text2'
'text3'
```

Unfortunately the template I define:

```
'$SELECTION$'
```

produces:

```
'text1
text2
text3'
```

which makes sense.

Is there any way to define a Live Template that will work on each line of my selection?

Comment: You can use multiple carets for that.

Comment: @LazyOne, can you provide an example?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Text+Editors#PhpStormforUsersofTextEditors-Multiplecaretsandselections/Sublime-styleMultipleColumns

Comment: @LazyOne decent solution but if I've 30+ lines, I don't want to `alt` + click each line.

Comment: There are solutions that do not require even single Alt+Click that works with blocks of lines (e.g. Ctrl x 2 + start selecting)

Comment: I think that this answer your question: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/multi-cursor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wrap in comment" is not a live template, but an action that is implemented in Java. In the same way, you can't accomplish what you need using a live template, but you can write a small plugin in Java to implement that feature. Please refer to the [Editor Basics tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics.html) to get started with writing the plugin.

Comment: can you provide an example or link to doc?