# How to wrap multiple lines with quotes each?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

This question is the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674568/surround-multiple-lines-with-quotes) which has an accepted answer that doesn't solve the problem. I have:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and the desired result is:

```
'line1'
'line2'
'line3'
```

The issue is not solved with multiple cursors as for more than 2 lines, it would require too much work to place `n * 2` cursors around `n` lines which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The suggested solution in the question mentioned earlier is to write a plugin in Java that achieves the desired outcome which I regard as an overkill and I'm certain there are built-in features that would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a regex search and replace may work here, if you don't need to use this too often. Enable the `In Selection` option (and the Regex option of course) and search for `(^.*$)`, and replace with `'$1'`.